# SQL: Calculated column using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Need one sql help. I am trying to calculate a view type column by taking into account date_selector and event_hour. So for a date_selector i need to have two view types such as 24H and 48H. 24H view is basically the same days data and 48H view should be previous day and current day. e.g for 2021-11-09 i have data till 5th event hour and for previous day, i have data till 3rd event_hour. so my 48H view calculation for date_selector 2021-11-09 should get both 08 and 09 data and 09th event hour will be added with 24.

```
2021-11-08,1,16
2021-11-08,2,18
2021-11-08,3,17
2021-11-09,1,12
2021-11-09,2,13
2021-11-09,3,15
2021-11-09,4,155
2021-11-09,5,156
2021-11-10,1,19
2021-11-10,2,20
2021-11-10,3,35
```

Output:

```
date_selector   event_hour  ops view_type
2021-11-08  1   16  24H
2021-11-08  2   18  24H
2021-11-08  3   17  24H
2021-11-09  1   12  24H
2021-11-09  2   13  24H
2021-11-09  3   15  24H
2021-11-09  4   155 24H
2021-11-09  5   156 24H
            
2021-11-09  1   16  48H
2021-11-09  2   18  48H
2021-11-09  3   17  48H
2021-11-09  25  12  48H
2021-11-09  26  13  48H
2021-11-09  27  15  48H
2021-11-09  28  155 48H
2021-11-09  29  156 48H
            
2021-11-10  1   19  24H
2021-11-10  2   20  24H
2021-11-10  3   35  24H
            
2021-11-10  1   12  48H
2021-11-10  2   13  48H
2021-11-10  3   15  48H
2021-11-10  4   155 48H
2021-11-10  5   156 48H
2021-11-10  25  19  48H
2021-11-10  26  20  48H
2021-11-10  27  35  48H
```

I could achive it by using union statement but checking if anyone have any better suggestion with join itself

```
with abc as (
    select '20211109'::date as date_selector, 1 as event_hour, '12' as ops
    union
    select '20211109'::date as date_selector, 2 as event_hour, '13' as ops
    union
    select '20211109'::date as date_selector, 3 as event_hour, '15' as ops
    union
    select '20211109'::date as date_selector, 4 as event_hour, '155' as ops
    union
    select '20211109'::date as date_selector, 5 as event_hour, '156' as ops
    union
    select '20211108'::date as date_selector, 1 as event_hour, '16' as ops
    union
    select '20211108'::date as date_selector, 2 as event_hour, '18' as ops
    union
    select '20211108'::date as date_selector, 3 as event_hour, '17' as ops
    union
    select '20211110'::date as date_selector, 1 as event_hour, '19' as ops
    union
    select '20211110'::date as date_selector, 2 as event_hour, '20' as ops
    union
    select '20211110'::date as date_selector, 3 as event_hour, '35' as ops
),
     bac as (
         select '20211109'::date as date_selector,
                '48-HOURS'       as view_type,
                '20211108'::date as start_date,
                '20211109'::date as end_date
/*union
select '20211110'::date ,'24-HOURS',    '20211110'::date,   '20211110'::date
union
select '20211110'::date ,'48-HOURS',    '20211109'::date,   '20211109'::date*/
     )
select b.date_selector,
       b.view_type,
       case when a.date_selector = b.date_selector then a.event_hour + 24 else a.event_hour end as event_hour,
       a.ops
from abc a
         join bac b
              on
                  a.date_selector between b.start_date and b.end_date
union
select a.date_selector,
       '24-HOURS' as view_type,
       a.event_hour,
       a.ops
from abc a
```

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ can help me to help you mate :)

Comment: So for 48H **every** source row should be present twice: for that same date and for the next date, right?

Comment: 48H every source row should be present twice: for that same date and for the prev date

Comment: What database are you actually using. Your question title says Oracle as does the tag. However the cast operator ( `'20211108'::date` ) is not supported by Oracle. That operator is (afaik) strictly Postgres.

Comment: its redshift database